# etcd 3.5 db_size growing constantly

Tags: etcd, defragmentation

I have 3-node etcd cluster version 3.5.2. I noticed a sitituation that endpoint's db_size is constantly growing. I have to perform compaction and defrag manually so that the db_size value cannot reach to limitation. I have not faced any similar problem in 3.2 version.

+--------------------+------------------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+--------------------+--------+
| ENDPOINT | ID | VERSION | DB SIZE | IS LEADER | IS LEARNER | RAFT TERM | RAFT INDEX | RAFT APPLIED INDEX | ERRORS |
+--------------------+------------------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+--------------------+--------+
| 10.201.64.106:2379 | 6af28eee6b8fd63a | 3.5.2 | 18 MB | true | false | 3 | 7509221 | 7509221 | |
| 10.201.64.107:2379 | 8t2ae31d2c14413e | 3.5.2 | 18 MB | false | false | 3 | 7509221 | 7509221 | |
| 10.222.82.121:2379 | c6131f42ed372576 | 3.5.2 | 18 MB | false | false | 3 | 7509221 | 7509221 | |

I expect the db size to not increase that fast. Or I shouldn't do the defrag process manually.

What should I do for this issue?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

DB Size is expected to grow without compaction and de-fragmentation.
You can set up auto compaction to make sure you dont hit the size limit.

All in all, 18 MB is quite low, default size limit is 2GB. What exactly are you worried about?

Side note: 3.5.2 is not recommended for production, you should use 3.5.3 or above. reference: https://groups.google.com/g/etcd-dev/c/sad9tgmKU7Y